# ORACLE SQL - Find number of active relief teachers, each teacher has 1 month before the teacher resigned

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in finding the number of relief teachers each teacher in a school has 1 to 3 months before their resignation. The `No_of_reliefs_1`, `No_of_reliefs_2`, `No_of_reliefs_3`  in the expected output should be equals to 0 if the latest `end_date` of the relief is not within 1 to 3 months of the teacher's `resign_date`.

`Start_dt` and `End_dt` here refers to the relief teacher's start date & end date. 
`No_of_relief` refers to the distinct `relief_id` each `teacher_id` has.

```
Teacher_ID Relief_ID Resign_date Start_date End_date No_of_Reliefs
12        20           2019-05-21  2019-03-22  2019-04-28  1
12        6            2019-05-21  2019-04-02  2019-04-22  1
12        10           2019-05-21  2019-01-01  2019-01-10  1
12        7            2019-05-21  2018-10-02  2018-11-15  1
23        21           null        2019-05-05  2019-05-18  1
23        18           null        2019-02-01  2019-03-30  1
23        30           null        2019-09-20  2018-12-20  1
1         4            2018-11-02  2018-08-10  2019-09-15  1
```

Expected output:

```
Teacher_ID Resign_date No_of_relief_1 No_of_relief_2 No_of_relief_3
12          2019-05-21  2              1               0
23          null        0              1               0 
1           2018-11-02  0              1               1
```

I understand that I may have to use the connectby clause to find the dates between `Start_dt` and `End_dt`. However, as I have a large number of data, this will take really long to execute. Thus, I'm wondering if there are other simpler ways to do it. 
Thank you! any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add table info, sample data and expected result to your question _as text_ and not as images

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson, I am new to this platform so I am not too sure how to do that :/ Anw I am only interested in a rough idea on how to get my desired output so Im wondering if anyone could help me out with that

Comment: [how to create a table in your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you! I have rephrased my question :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use aggregate (GROUP BY) function to count the number of reliefs for each teacher. Use CASE to make the sums conditional.

```
select teacher_id
       ,resign_date
       ,sum(case 
              when resign_date is null then 0
              when end_date >= resign_date - interval '1' month then no_of_reliefs
              else 0
            end ) as no_of_reliefs_1
       ,sum(case 
              when resign_date is null then 0
              when end_date < resign_date - interval '1' month 
                   and end_date >= resign_date - interval '2' month then no_of_reliefs
              else 0
            end ) as no_of_reliefs_2
       ,sum(case 
              when resign_date is null then 0
              when end_date < resign_date - interval '2' month 
                   and end_date >= resign_date - interval '3' month then no_of_reliefs
              else 0
            end ) as no_of_reliefs_3
from your_table
group by teacher_id
        ,resign_date
```

---

Note: your expected output does not appear to be derived from your sample output following the rules you published. I suspect this is a cut'n'paste issue: for instance how can teacher 23 have `No_of_relief_2` = 1 when they haven't resigned?  So I have made the best interpretation I can. If this doesn't work the way you expect please edit your question to clarify your requirements and align the required output.

Comment: You understand your rules better than I do. So you should revise my code to fit your understanding.